# Compare two datarow values with their appropriate type

Tags: c#, compare

I am wondering if there is a better way to compare two data rows' values, here's what I got, I tried generics with an IComparer but it requires to pass the type at compile-time, which is not possible here.

```
    public static bool ByteArrayEquals(byte[] range1, int offset1, byte[] range2, int offset2, int count)
    {
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (range1[offset1 + i] != range2[offset2 + i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        return true;
    }
    
    bool DataRowObjectEquals(object dr1, object dr2, Type t)
    {
        if (dr1 == DBNull.Value && dr2 == DBNull.Value)
            return true;
        if (dr1 == DBNull.Value && dr2 != DBNull.Value || dr1 != DBNull.Value && dr2 == DBNull.Value)
            return false;
        //at this point we know both have actual values
        if(t.Name == "Decimal")
            return (decimal)dr1 == (decimal)dr2;             
        if (t.Name == "String")
            return (string)dr1 == (string)dr2;
        if (t.Name == "DateTime")
            return (DateTime)dr1 == (DateTime)dr2;
        if (t.Name == "Int32")
            return (int)dr1 == (int)dr2;
        if (t.Name == "Int16")
            return (short)dr1 == (short)dr2;
        if (t.Name == "Byte[]")
            return ByteArrayEquals((byte[])dr1, 0, (byte[])dr2, 0, ((byte[])dr1).Length);
        else
            throw new Exception("type not found");
    }
```

and this is how I use the function, we will always have the same columns and data types on both data tables

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in wo1.DataSet.Tables["TABLE"].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().OrderBy(p => p.ColumnName).ToList())
{
    if (!DataRowObjectEquals(dr1[dc.ColumnName], dr2[dc.ColumnName], dr1.Table.Columns[dc.ColumnName].DataType))
    {                            
        Console.WriteLine("\tCOLUMNS: " +
            dc.ColumnName + " (" + dc.DataType.ToString() + ") have different values: {" +
            dr1[dc.ColumnName] + "," + dr2[dc.ColumnName] + "}");
    }                            
}
```

Comment: You have to define what "better" means. Do know that codereview.se does exist. They review and suggest improvements on working code.

Comment: ahh I didn't know that, thanks a lot for your help, I guess better means without hard-coding types.

Comment: "I tried generics with an IComparer but it requires to pass the type at compile-time, which is not possible here." Are you saying your code does not work yet?

Comment: You can create your own equality using Equals() and GetHashCode(). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-5.0